# Which one should I use for dimension reduction with PCA in MATLAB, pcacov or eigs?

Tags: matlab, pca, dimensionality-reduction

I'm trying to reduce my training set dimension from 1296*70000 to 128*70000.
I wrote Below code:

```
A=DicH;
[M N]=size(A);
mu=mean(A,2);%mean of columns

Phi=zeros(M,N);
C=zeros(M,M);
for j=1:N
    Phi(:,j)=A(:,j)-mu;
    c=Phi(:,j)*(Phi(:,j))';
    C=C+c;
end

C=C/N;%Covariance Dictionary
[V,landa] = eigs(C,128);%Eigen Vectors & Eigen Values
E=V'*Phi;%Reduced Dic
%*******************Using Pcacov*****************
%S=zeros(M,1);
%[U,landa] = pcacov(C);%Eigen Vectors & Eigen Values
% for k=1:128;
%     S=V(:,k)+S;
%     U(:,k)=S;
% end
%E=U'*Phi;%Reduced Dic
```

I get two different answers! Which one should I use "eigs" or "pcacov"??

Comment: You get two different answers because they use different methods of reducing dimensionality. If you do "model selection" you should try to have some kind of test set that gives you an estimate of which one does better.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm trying to simulate a paper about face recognition via sparse representation, and after creating a dictionary of histograms I have to reduce dimension via PCA, I tried both but don't get the correct answer for final face recognition process (My codes on raw face images worked efficiently)!!  I don't have any idea about PCA's output and Don't know if I implemented the PCA correct or not!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take advantage of the built-in functions in Matlab, and use the `pca` function directly, or even the `cov` function if you want to compare `eigs` to `pcaconv`.

Now to answer your question, both return the same eigenvectors but not in the same order. See the following example:

```
>> load hald
>> covx = cov(ingredients);
>> [COEFF,latent] = pcacov(covx)

COEFF =

   -0.0678   -0.6460    0.5673    0.5062
   -0.6785   -0.0200   -0.5440    0.4933
    0.0290    0.7553    0.4036    0.5156
    0.7309   -0.1085   -0.4684    0.4844


latent =

  517.7969
   67.4964
   12.4054
    0.2372

>> [V, D] = eigs(covx)                    

V =

    0.5062    0.5673    0.6460   -0.0678
    0.4933   -0.5440    0.0200   -0.6785
    0.5156    0.4036   -0.7553    0.0290
    0.4844   -0.4684    0.1085    0.7309


D =

    0.2372         0         0         0
         0   12.4054         0         0
         0         0   67.4964         0
         0         0         0  517.7969

>>
```

In your code, you overwrite the result of `pcavconv` in the commented-out section with a transformation of the result of `eigs` so it is not clear what your are comparing at this point. When using `pcacov`, you just need to extract the 128 first columns of `U`.

Comment: Thanks, You are right about built-in functions, it takes less time!
I tried different Matrices (magic(4) ,rand(4), ..), but results aren't the same! 
Actually I want to know,  pcacov or eigs (maybe both) can be used for Dimension reduction?! and what difference the results make? 
Is the code correct for dimension reduction?!

Comment: I think you meant to say "different order". You should probably be using `eig` rather the slower, more specialized `eigs`, even though the ordering is not guaranteed, no?